# xcode 6 is iphone 5 no longer 568 points in height?

Tags: ios, xcode6, iphone-5

So I'm trying to update my game to fit the iPhone 6 properly and i see now that when i run my game on the iPhone 5 simulator, everything is fitting as if it were an iPhone 4. I use if statements to determine the height of the device:

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    mylabel4.fontSize = 35;
    mylabel4.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) -145, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) -130);
} else {
    mylabel4.fontSize = 35;
    mylabel4.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) -110, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 130);
}
```

And like i said when i run the iPhone 5 simulator, it runs the code in the 'else' bracket. Its like the iPhone 5 is no longer 568 points in height. This was working fine until i download Xcode 6? What's going on here?

Comment: Did you try logging the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height`?

Comment: @rebello95 Did what you said and found the problem. In my game the phone is turned on its side. Before, size.height for the iPhone 5 would be 568, but not anymore. Now, size.height = 320 and size.width = 568, it got switched.

Comment: I have the exact same if statement in one of my apps, just checked and it is working as expected. Have you tried what rebello95 suggested and log out [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIScreen bounds behavior has changed in iOS8. Previously it would always give you width and height of the screen in portrait (so 320 x 568 on the iPhone 5), but in iOS8 it will give you width and height with respect to whatever orientation you're in, i.e. in landscape you would get 568 x 320.

If you want to get the bounds in portrait (like before), use:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add launch images for the iPhone and the simulator will display the proper points. Weird bug.